# protobuf-net usage of GetProto when sharing field classes

Tags: java, compilation, protobuf-net

I have some C# classes on my server side (only for serialization), with the intention of use Java deserialization on the client side.

For this purpose, I assume I'm gonna need to extract the *.proto* files, so I'm using `Serializer.GetProto<T>`.

Some of the classes share some types, like

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class ClassA {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int a { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassB
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int x { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ClassA a { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassC
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int z { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ClassA a { get; set; }
}
```

Where ClassB and ClassC contain a member of type ClassA.

When we call `Serializer.GetProto<ClassB>()`, the resultant *.proto* file contains the definition for **ClassA**, and when we call `Serializer.GetProto<ClassC<>()`, the resultant file contains the definition for **ClassA** too.

- Shall this cause any inconveniences when the Java dev team uses *protoc* compiler to generate *.java* classes?
- Is there a way to extract shared classes alone to a different *.proto* file and make the others look for that shared proto message?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, no: there is no support for that. I suppose (thinking aloud here) I could add something like:

```
[ProtoContract(SchemaFile="some.proto")] // this does not exist today!
public class ClassA {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

and have `GetProto` treat that as a break when resolving types - adding the necessary schema import instead. This probably isn't particularly hard - but: it doesn't exist at the moment. You would have to split the schema manually.

Comment: Ok. I suspect the answer may be No but, anyway, is there some attribute annotation so we can tell GetProto() which fields may be exported to the resultant string? I mean something like [ProtoMember(N, exportable = false)]